# Java NIO downloaded file is different than web browser

Tags: java, nio, download

I am trying to download a `.torrent` file from a URL using Java NIO. Downloading this file from a web browser results in a proper torrent file which can be used. Downloading in Java results in a different/corrupted file.

This is the code I am using to perform the download:

```
URL url = new URL("http://torcache.net/torrent/E4B5326AA31D1AE0C30E05129193E87AA086F5F8.torrent");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.torrent");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
```

Comment: You have to call the transfer methods in a loop. They aren't guaranteed to complete the transfer in a single iteration. That's why they return a count.

Comment: @EJP How would I be able to guarantee transfer? (How can I query the file size)